# Highchart using javascript to display on every row of gridview using div element

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview

C# gridview has a templatefield which contains a single div with the ID container. I have the following javascript which creates a highchart graph and puts the graph in this div on the front end. For some reason the graph is only being displayed on the first row of the gridview and not every row. My end goal is to display a box plot graph for each row. The data the box plot uses is being retrieved from the database and parsed to javascript using JSON.PARSE and this works ok. I need to get the graph to output on each row of the gridview:

JS:

```
function CreateBoxPlot() {


var hv = $('#hiddenvariable').val();
alert(hv);

var chart;
var titleText = 'Test Chart Title';
var subTitleText = 'Test Chart Subtitle';
var type = 'boxplot';
var data = [JSON.parse(hv).map(item => parseInt(item))]; //Doesnt work in IE

console.log(data);

$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: { type: type, inverted: true },
        title: { text: titleText },
        subtitle: { text: subTitleText },
        legend: { enabled: false },
        tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            crosshairs: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                pointWidth: 50
            }
        },

        xAxis: {
            visible: false

        },
        yAxis: {

            visible: true,
            title: {
                text: 'Values'
            },

            plotLines: [{
                value: 80,
                color: 'red',
                width: 2

            }]

        }
    });

    chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    chart.addSeries({ data: data });


});
```

}

ASPX:

```
                              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DaysGraph" HeaderStyle-Width="30%" >
                       <ItemTemplate>
                           <div id="container" >

                           </div>

                       </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

C#

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cn.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();


    var chartValues = new List<string>();
    var chartValues2 = new List<string>();

    string str = reader["ChartData"].ToString();

    string[] strList = str.Split(','); //seperate the hobbies by comma

    // convert it in json
    dataStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(strList, Formatting.None);

    hiddenvariable.Value = dataStr;
```

Comment: and the data are ?

Comment: The data is based on a column in a database. Example output is 60,62,69,75,77 which is stored in a hidden field and used for data in high charts to plot the box plot. Updated above to show C# code to get the data from sql reader

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the reason is because you have add it to a GridView, that is repeat the same id `id="container"`, so its logical that only the first is plot. So when you ask to plot the data to an ID, its only find the first one.

```
   <ItemTemplate>
       <div id="container" >
       </div>
   </ItemTemplate>
```

add a different id on each row base on some database id- eg: `<div id="container1" >`, `<div id="container2" >`, `<div id="container3" >`

alternative here

```
('#container').highcharts({
```

don't use the id, but add some class, and capture them all, but you still need to add different data base on some id.

---

### Solution

How you can add some parameters on rendered side to find the appropriate data for each line.
First of all render the `div`and adding some data inside that you get using javascript.
So on GridView you add

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="header" >
    <ItemTemplate >
     <%#getDivContainer(Container.DataItem)%>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

and then on code behind send the `div` with a `data-id`

```
protected string getDateAndGraph(object oItem)
{
    // read the id from your data set
    var CurrentID = (int) DataBinder.Eval(oItem, "ID");

    return string.Format("<div id="container_{0}" class="graph" data-id="{0}"></div>", CurrentID);
}
```

now on javascript side, you pass each of the previous elements and place them the correct data on each one, base on the id

```
// init all of them
$(function () {
    $('.graph').highcharts({
        // init 
        chart: { type: type, inverted: true },
        title: { text: titleText },
        .... rest of .....
    })
});

// here you add the correct data to each line
$( ".graph" ).each(function( index, element ) { 
    chart = $(element).highcharts();

    // now read the id, and load the appropriate data
    MyDataID = $(element).data( "id" );
    var hv = $('#hiddenvariable' + MyDataID).val();
    var data = [JSON.parse(hv).map(item => parseInt(item))];

    chart.addSeries({ data: data });

});
```

Comment: @RA19 give me some moments to write it.

Comment: <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DaysGraph" HeaderStyle-Width="30%" >
                           <ItemTemplate>
                                           
                        <%#getDateAndGraph(Container.DataItem)%>
                    </ItemTemplate>   
                             
                           </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

Text is not allowed between the opening and closing for element template field

Comment: @RA19 Find what the error is on your project, because is working on mine

Comment: It is saying text is not allowed in between the item template tag. Can you send me full code? The markup?

Comment: @RA19 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="header" >
 <ItemTemplate >
  <%#getDivContainer(Container.DataItem)%>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

Comment: var CurrentID = (int) DataBinder.Eval(oItem, "MeasureID"); I am reading the ID from my data set but it is saying Additional information: Specified cast is not valid on the above syntax 

What is wrong here? I see you had 'ID' in your code - but i dont have ID as a column so it saying it doe not exist in data row.

Comment: Also what is  data-id="{0}" ? Should this start from 0 or should this be the value from the data row?

Comment: Can’t get it to work because of the above error. I have used measureId as that’s what the dataID is. How do I adjust the code given above to use measureId. Please note measureId does not start from 0. It starts from 46 as the first ID value?